How can I define class methods in a different file in typescript, while controlling their visibility, and have them be considered inside the class?
I want to define some class methods in a different file to my main class body for organizational and testing purposes.  I've seen various workarounds for this.  So far as I can tell, some of them don't allow you to set the visibility of the method, making them automatically public (like doing it with Object.assign()), and none of them let you access private members of the class.
Using .bind(this) allows me to set the visibility of the method, but then that method can't access private properties of the class, because it's not considered "within" the class.
I want to do this because:

It makes for more organized code, but also

I want to test a private method using something like jest, which requires me to call the method, which I can't do while it's private.  If I could have it defined in it's own file, I could load it independently from the rest of the class, and perform my unit tests.


This seems like such basic functionality, I don't understand why it wouldn't be included.

"I want to define some class methods in a different file to my main class body for organizational purposes." - if you need to do that, your class is too large and you should refactor it

In general you shouldn't have to test private methods. If there's some helper functions that you want to test separately, extract them into separate functions, but you cannot extract an entire method. If you really want to, just @ts-ignore the call to the private method.

Sorry, but "I prefer MSG, go there instead" is not a valid answer to the question "How do you get to Carnegie Hall?".  If you prefer to keep your entire class in one file, and to never test your private methods, that's fine, but this personal preference is just not relevant to the issue here.

The simple answer is that this is not possible. My comments were in response to "This seems like such basic functionality, I don't understand why it wouldn't be included." The language is designed so that classes are a lexical unit inside a single module (file), not spread across multiple ones. If you prefer to ignore that, you'll need to pick a different language.

Right now there doesn't seem to be much to do with this question. There's no [mre] so we're just talking about code in the abstract, and then the ask seems to be for something TypeScript can't do because JavaScript doesn't have partial classes, and so TypeScript can't be expected to allow private access across pieces of partial classes. What should we do here? Write an answer that says "no, this isn't possible"?

@jcalz If it is definitively and demonstrably not possible, yes.

@DuncanMarshall What kind of demonstration do you expect? It's hard to prove negatives.

I need to see a [mre] before I could say for sure what is and isn't possible. Right now I strongly suspect it's impossible, but a concrete code sample would help a lot.  I mean, you can certainly start messing with prototypes to emulate partial classes; you say things about visibility but I don't know if you're talking private or # or protected or just not exporting type information. Let's see a [mre] and then we can all be on the same page.
